# Extracting first word after a specific expression in R

Tags: r, dataframe, text-mining, stringr

I have a column that contains thousands of descriptions like this (example) :

| Description |
| --- |
| Building a hospital in the city of LA, USA |
| Building a school in the city of NYC, USA |
| Building shops in the city of Chicago, USA |

I'd like to create a column with the first word after "city of", like that :

| Description | City |
| --- | --- |
| Building a hospital in the city of LA, USA | LA |
| Building a school in the city of NYC, USA | NYC |
| Building shops in the city of Chicago, USA | Chicago |

I tried with the following code after seeing this topic [Extracting string after specific word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66141475/extracting-string-after-specific-word), but my column is only filled with missing values

```
library(stringr)

df$city <- data.frame(str_extract(df$Description, "(?<=city of:\\s)[^;]+"))

df$city <- data.frame(str_extract(df$Description, "(?<=of:\\s)[^;]+"))
```

I took a look at the dput() and the output is the same than the descriptions i see in the dataframe directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution

This should make the trick for the data you showed:

```r
df$city <- str_extract(df$Description, "(?<=city of )(\\w+)")

df
#>                                  Description    city
#> 1 Building a hospital in the city of LA, USA      LA
#> 2  Building a school in the city of NYC, USA     NYC
#> 3 Building shops in the city of Chicago, USA Chicago
```

---

### Alternative

However, in case you want the whole string till the first comma (for example in case of cities with a blank in the name), you can go with:

```r
df$city <- str_extract(df$Description, "(?<=city of )(.+)(?=,)")
```

Check out the following example:

```r
df <- data.frame(Description = c("Building a hospital in the city of LA, USA",
                                 "Building a school in the city of NYC, USA",
                                 "Building shops in the city of Chicago, USA",
                                 "Building a church in the city of Salt Lake City, USA"))

str_extract(df$Description, "(?<=the city of )(\\w+)")
#> [1] "LA"      "NYC"     "Chicago" "Salt"   

str_extract(df$Description, "(?<=the city of )(.+)(?=,)")
#> [1] "LA"             "NYC"            "Chicago"        "Salt Lake City"
```

---

### Documentation

Check out `?regex`:

> Patterns (?=...) and (?!...) are zero-width positive and negative
> lookahead assertions: they match if an attempt to match the ...
> forward from the current position would succeed (or not), but use up
> no characters in the string being processed. Patterns (?<=...) and
> (?<!...) are the lookbehind equivalents: they do not allow repetition
> quantifiers nor \C in ....